# Central limit theorem: Expected value of input distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm using the below code to show how a large number of random numbers in an exponential distribution converges to a normal distribution.

If I put both 'mu' and 'sigma2' to 1, then the normal distribution is centered over 0. But if for any other value it moves to the side.

Why is this? Is any specific expected value and variance more correct than any other here?

````
set.seed(2345)

n <- 5000 
M <- 1000

likf_matris <- matrix(rexp(n * M), nrow = n, ncol = M)

summa <- colSums(likf_matris)

mu <- 1/1 # expected value

sigma2 <- 1/1 # Variance

stand <- (summa - n * mu) / sqrt(n * sigma2)

hist(stand,
main = "7. Standardiserade observationer för 
exponentialfördelning, n=5000",
ylab = "Antal",
xlab = "Värde",
ylim=c(0,250),
xlim=c(-4,4))

```
````

Comment: What do you input if $\mu\neq 1$ and $\sigma^2\neq 1$? Give an example.

Comment: The mean and variance of an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda$ is $\frac 1\lambda$ and $\frac1{\lambda^2}$, respectively. Type ?rexp in R and you will see that R assumes, by default, an exponential distribution with $\lambda = 1$. If you typed rexp(n * M, 2) and put mu = 0.5 and sigma = 0.25 you would not see the shift